# Grunt similar tool for PHP pages?

Tags: javascript, html, php, framework, package-manager

I have been using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) with [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and [Assemble.io](http://assemble.io/), SASS but I will need to work with PHP pages and database so I am looking for a great tool like Grunt which allows me to use PHP pages / MySql database.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details – then [edit] your question and see if you can implement some improvements. This will greatly increase your chances for good answers as well!

Answer (score 3):

I think [Phing](https://www.phing.info/) is a good choice but why don't you use Grunt for PHP as well? Why would you pick a new tool only for PHP?

(you could install grunt-php, grunt-phpunit, grunt-phpmd, grunt-phpspec, grunt-phplint and so on ... you might start with [this](http://fettblog.eu/blog/2013/11/17/the-magic-of-grunt-contrib-connect-and-how-to-run-php-with-it/))

---

List of useful links to integrate grunt with Yii:

- [how to deploy](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/467/using-grunt-for-deploying-client-scripts/)
- [gruntfile generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-gruntfile-yii)
- [Yii2 asset processing with grunt](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.org/structure-asset-processing-with-grunt/)

Comment: Thanks Harcos, You are right actually. I just don't know how to integrate grunt with my PHP framework (YII) and make them work together. But absolutely, I think I will keep Grunt and use it with my PHP framework, somehow!

Comment: @MaRco85 I've edited my answer, now you can see a list of useful links to get started with the integration

Comment: That is so helpful!! Thank you very much for that and I am definitely starting to work on it!

Comment: you are welcome :)